# GNOME Shell User Theme Extension

Tags: 11.10, gnome, themes, extension

How do I activate the gnome-shell user-theme extension in Oneiric with GNOME 3.2? I've installed the package `gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme`  but can't find anywhere on how to activate it. I thought the `gnome-shell-extensions-tool` was the way but when I run it nothing happens.

Comment: did you install `gnome-tweak-tool`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install GNOME Tweak Tool: [graphically](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gnome-tweak-tool/) or use the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Once installed, open GNOME Tweak Tool (should show up as "Advanced Settings" in the menu) and activate User Theme extension.

Please note that to be able to install or change GNOME Shell themes using GNOME Tweak Tool, after enabling the User Theme extension you may need to restart Tweak Tool or the whole GNOME Shell (press ALT + F2 and enter "r" or log out and log back in). This is not required for other extensions.

Comment: Great! Shouldn't there be a more standard (easier) way of activating these things, though?

Comment: shell-extensions aren't "officially" supported -- yet. The GNOME team were too busy trying to get 3 out the door to worry about customisation (and 3.2 largely consisted of bugfixes and repairing some idiosyncracies), but there was enough of the basic functionality there that people were able to write gnome-tweak-tool and start making extensions and themes before the gnome team got around to integrating it properly. It should be a standard part of the system settings from 3.4 onward.

Comment: Mark the reload in fat pls :p