# Tighten Items in Gnome Shell Panel?

Tags: gnome

Am really liking what you can do with Gnome Shell. The extensions are very nice and there's some very good ones that available. Is there an easy way to tighten up the items on the panel... below is what's on my screen right now...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a simpler way to achieve this, it is an extension which modifies the hpadding for the right box only, which is basically enough for most. To install the extension click [THIS LINK](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/355/status-area-horizontal-spacing/) and click the toggle switch once, it will change to On and a box will come up asking you if you'd like to install. You will now see automagical spacing decrease. This works on 3.2, and 3.4, for 3.4 once it is installed you can configure it by refreshing the page and clicking the Preferences icon.

The OLD method to achieve this is to edit the default theme, but since it will get overwritten by updates, you should instead make a copy of the default theme, and edit the copy. You will need the user themes extension enabled to do it this way. To install the user themes extension refer to [THIS LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64416/gnome-shell-user-theme-extension) and then read below(at the bottom) to copy the default theme.

To edit the default theme you would run <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or open a terminal:

```
gnomesu gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css
```

Now find and change hpadding to the desired setting: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, hpadding Note that hpadding only exists on 2 lines, here is where you will see it:

```
.panel-button {
    -natural-hpadding: 12px;
    -minimum-hpadding: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ccc;
    transition-duration: 100;
}
```

If you want to copy the theme instead you will open a terminal again and run for example

```
sudo cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ ~/.themes/GnomeShell/gnome-shell/
```

You also have to create a default theme.json file in the newly created gnome-shell directory, to do this with terminal `touch ~/.themes/GnomeShell/gnome-shell/theme.json` and `gnomesu gedit ~/.themes/GnomeShell/gnome-shell/theme.json` Paste the following:

`{ 
   "shell-theme": {
   "name": "Gnome Shell", 
   "author": "l300lvl", 
   "version": "1.0",
   "type":   "custom",
   "thumbnail": "preview.jpg", 
   "url": "http://l300lvl.co.nr/" 
    }
}`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to save.

This will place the theme in your local users themes directory, i.e /home/USER/.themes/

To copy with Nautilus instead use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>(or paste in a terminal), `gnomesu nautilus` and browse to the above directory.

Once you've either copied the theme and done the desired edits, and enabled the extension mentioned above and then selected the theme, or edited the default theme, if you still don't see the correct results try restarting the shell: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `r` or reload the theme <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `rt`